# nhibernate casts smallint to int in where clause

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

```
var calls = _session.Query<CallTable>()
                    .Where(x => x.Rated == (short)0)
                    .ToList();

This sql is being generated:
select <....>
from   [CallTable] cdrcalltmp0_
where  cdrcalltmp0_.ClientId = 526 /* @p0 */
       and cast(cdrcalltmp0_.Rated as INT) = 0 /* @p1 */
```

Rated is a smallint in the database. Why is it casting a smallint to int in order to compare with a short?

Comment: Could it be that your object is Int in your entity? Can you also explain me why are you casting that 0?

Answer (score 0):

`SmallInt` and `Short` are different data types (even if they are similar, there is no way for the SQL processor to know this when it received the data.) Since SQL server does not have a `Short` data type, it presumably converts it to an integer. [This](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.dotnet.nhibernate.devel/1737) Seems to support that assumption.

This is probably the default behavior for short data types being queried from SQL through c#. Look at this example of how to fix something similar, if it helps: [nhibernate fluent bool to smallint mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044310/nhibernate-fluent-bool-to-smallint-mapping). Otherwise, you may need to change settings for your connection to do this.